# Room Database Migration doesn't properly handle New table creation

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

The log contains :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle broadBandPlans(duleaf.duapp.splash.data.local.models.FixedPlanLocal).

*Expected:
TableInfo{name='broadBandPlans', columns={speed=Column{name='speed', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, prodID=Column{name='prodID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}*

*Found:
TableInfo{name='broadBandPlans', columns={prodID=Column{name='prodID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, speed=Column{name='speed', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}*
```

Below is the FixedPlanLocal Class, Can someone guide me here why Room is expecting speed as the first column and then prodID, how should I solve this?

```
@Entity(tableName = "broadBandPlans")
public class FixedPlanLocal {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "prodID")
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    String prodID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "speed")
    String speed;


    public FixedPlanLocal(@NonNull String prodID, String speed) {
        this.prodID = prodID;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getProdID() {
        return prodID;
    }

    public void setProdID(@NonNull String prodID) {
        this.prodID = prodID;
    }

    public String getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(String speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.prodID.equals(((FixedPlanLocal) obj).prodID);
    }
}
,
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the **speed** column, of the table, using the NOT NULL constraint, therefore you need **@NonNull** in the entity for the speed column:-

- Expected is as per the Entity
- Found is as per the Table

Instead of :-

```
public String getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}
```

Use :-

```
@NonNull
public String getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}
```

The column order is irrelevant and Room seems to quite persistently not order them as expected *(i.e. not as per either the Table or Entity for the expected list)*.

What is important are the values must be consistent between expected and found.

In your case The Entity (expected) and the Table (Found) for the speed column are :-

```
name='speed', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0
name='speed', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0
```

You can easily see that notNull is **false** for the Entity (@NotNull is not coded) but **true** for the Table.

The fix is to either add @NotNull to the Entity (as above) or the change the Table definition so that the speed column does not have the NOT NULL constraint.

- Note, in some situations e.g. when using java primary types in the Entity, that @NotNull is implied (in such situations you have to change the table (or use an equivalent object instead of the java primary type e.g. use `Integer` instead of `int`))

Comment: Thanks Mike, the below code fixed it though I didn't understand why the Speed Column is expected as NotNull, I have defined only prodID as Notnull.                          
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "speed")
    String speed;

Comment: @rkdroid with ROOM the table must adhere to what the Entity expects otherwise you get the mismatch and the Expected/Found issue as the schema as per the Entities is compared against the table when building the database at run time. Typically the Entities drive the creation of the underlying tables but when migrating the changes are not made by Room but by the migration code.